# Rename [google-form] to [google-forms]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Tag [google-form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-form) is the only tag that does not conform to the naming convention of Google products with pluralized names and to the product's official name. There is no "Google Form", there are only "Google Forms", as much as there are:

- "Google Contacts" [google-contacts-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-contacts-api)
- "Google Docs" [google-docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-docs)
- "Google Groups" [google-groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-groups)
- "Google Maps" [google-maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps)
- "Google Sheets" [google-sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets)
- "Google Slides" [google-slides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-slides)
- "Google Sites" [google-sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sites)
- "Google Tasks" [google-tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-tasks)

**Proposal**

Just rename the tag [google-form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-form) to [google-forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-forms)

Comment: OK, this is easy. Too bad they're not all this easy.

Comment: @CodyGray - glad I could dig out one for once, thank you for taking care of it :) [for god's sake, even this change seems to be polarizing]

Comment: Probably not polarizing so much as deemed pointless by certain voters. It's a position I can understand, and would agree with, were it not merely a click or two for me.

Comment: @CodyGray - it was a joke rant :) In all seriousness, we would do it ourselves, but creating a tag, transferring wiki, then voting to synonymize is just too many moving parts for something so simple - so again, thank you!